# Android: best payment gateway for donation app

Tags: java, android, paypal, payment-gateway, stripe-payments

I'm trying to make a charity donation app but I cannot figure out which payment gateway is suitable to use. I have done some research and found about Stripe and Android Pay and PayPal but I'm still not sure. Does anyone have an idea on which payment gateway is best for a donation app.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't speak for PayPal, but I can tell you this.  Stripe supports the basics and also plays well with Android Pay.  The thing it can't do is collect ACH or BitCoin right now, so you'd only be able to collect Credit Cards.

Comment: Thanks! Will go for Stripe then

Comment: @sirvon - Actually, Stripe does not support these in the Android Bindings.  It's only available in the Java Bindings.